# bitmap to file that can be uploaded via async

Tags: android, file, asynchronous, upload, bitmap

After a day of headaches due to previous problems implementing a working photo upload system I feel im in the home stretch. my last and final step is to allow my users to upload a image once it has been cropped.

after cropping takes place I have access to a bitmap and a imageView that is using the bitmap.The async request lib im using is : http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

and the api im using is setup in such a way that i need to send over a "file" like so:

```
File myFile = new File("/path/to/file.png");
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
try {
    params.put("profile_picture", myFile);
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {}
```

What are my options for turning my bitmap into a "file"

Answer (score 5):

You can save Bitmap to file using [Bitmap.compress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) method. Just provide proper FileOutputStream as argument.

You can also upload image without using files, just save it to byte array and then upload as that array.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, out);
byte[] myByteArray = out.toByteArray();
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("profile_picture", new ByteArrayInputStream(myByteArray), "image.png");
```

Comment: FYI: PNG is a lossless format, meaning that the 85 will  be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                        "/to";
File dir = new File(file_path);
if(!dir.exists)
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "file.png");
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
```

and put the below permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```